# Connect to rabbitmq via remote computer

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have windows 7 64 bit, i've installed rabbitmq, is there a way to connect to the rabbitmq from remote computer(via code and ui) ? If so, how?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

From code -

[Remote procedure call (RPC)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html)

From UI -

[Management Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

Comment: Thank for the reply,  maybe i didnt wrote it clear, if i use localhost:15672 i get access to the rabbit but if i use my public and private ip i can't connect, via code . so i want to know what i need to do for this to work (connect to remote rabbitmq via code and public ip)

Comment: Check your firewall and allow port 15672. Connect to rabbit using your public ip.

Comment: I open port 15672 in firewall (i did new rule in inbound rules and specified this port), but still can't access to the rabbit, even from the ui